# Changing toolbar title in each fragment using MVVM and Databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am looking to change the toolbar title,which is in my main activity, in my fragments page. My project is based on MVVM Architecture, with databinding.

This is my main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.lalsoft.toolbar_mvvm_databinding.viewmodel.MainViewModel" />
</data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:navigationOnClickListener="@{()->viewModel.navBackClicked()}"
            app:title="@{viewModel.toolbarTitle}"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is my mainActivity.kt

```
private const val TAG = "MainActivity"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
private lateinit var dataBinding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    //setSupportActionBar(dataBinding.toolbar)
    //dataBinding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back)
    viewModel.navClicked.observe(this, navClickObserver)
    viewModel.toolbarTitle.observe(this, toolbarTitleObserver)
    dataBinding.viewModel = viewModel

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
            R.id.fragment_container,
            FirstFragment()
        ).commit()
    }

}

private val navClickObserver = Observer<Boolean> {
    supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    Log.e(TAG, "Nav Back clicked")
}

private val toolbarTitleObserver = Observer<String> {
    Log.e(TAG, "Title set : $it")
}

}
```

And this is my MainViewModel

```
private const val TAG = "MainViewModel"

open class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
val toolbarTitle: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
private val _navClicked: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
val navClicked: LiveData<Boolean> = _navClicked
init {
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside Init")
    //toolbarTitle.value ="Main Activity"
}

fun navBackClicked() {
    _navClicked.value = true
}

}
```

Now i am trying to change the toolbar title in FragmentViewModel by changing the mutable toolbarTitle of my mainActivityViewModel.

```
private const val TAG = "FirstViewModel"

class FirstViewModel : MainViewModel() {

private val _navigateToDetails = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()
val navigateToFragment: LiveData<Event<String>>
    get() = _navigateToDetails

init {
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside Init")
    toolbarTitle.value="First Fragment"
}

fun onBtnClick() {
    _navigateToDetails.value = Event("Second Fragment")
}
}
```

This is my fragment class

```
private const val TAG = "FirstFragment"

class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var viewModel: FirstViewModel
private lateinit var dataBinding: FirstFragmentBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.first_fragment, container, false)
    return dataBinding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FirstViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.toolbarTitle.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, toolbarTitleObserver)
    viewModel.navigateToFragment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, navigateToFragmentObserver)
    //(activity as MainActivity?)!!.toolbar.title = "Check"
    dataBinding.viewModel = viewModel

}


private val toolbarTitleObserver = Observer<String> {
    Log.e(TAG, "Title set : $it")
    //(activity as MainActivity?)!!.toolbar.title = "Check"
    //Log.e(TAG, "Title set : Check")
}

private val navigateToFragmentObserver = Observer<Event<String>> { it ->
    it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { // Only proceed if the event has never been handled
        Log.i(TAG, "checkIt string $it")
        parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
            R.id.fragment_container,
            SecondFragment()
        ).addToBackStack(null).commit()

    }
}
}
```

Eventhough its observing the toolbarTitle correctly,the Title in my program is not changing..
Hope to get some help to get out of this issue.

This is my sample git project where i am trying to do this : [github](https://github.com/Shijilal/ToolBar-MVVM-DataBinding)

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with the same!
I think the problem is the lifecycleowner. But could not find an answer.
Currently I observe the values from the the ViewModel and assign the values inside the observer.
But I think there is a better way!

Answer (score 0):

If your Fragment is using a ViewModel should be scoped to a host Activity, use by activityViewModels() delegate:

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
      private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
    }
```

I think also this answer will help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62560605

When you use by viewModels, you are creating a ViewModel scoped to that individual Fragment - this means each Fragment will have its own individual instance of that ViewModel class. If you want a single ViewModel instance scoped to the entire Activity, you'd want to use by activityViewModels